# Mule ClassNotFoundException for class existing in a library in the class path

Tags: mule, classloader, esb

I have a class in a Mule application which resides in a jar of a third party library. The library gets included in the lib folder after the project builds so it is definitely in the classpath. The class is then used in a Mule component. The applications deploys successfully in AnyPoint Studio'sembedded server. However, when the Mule component is processing data, Mule complains that it can't find the class. 
As soon as the line with the following code snippet is encountered it throws the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

```
populator.put(ScanType.MRI,container);
```

Here is a portion of the stacktrace:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tcfg.utils.defn.Populator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.findClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:175)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleApplicationClassLoader.findClass(MuleApplicationClassLoader.java:134)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.loadClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:119)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I also know that this is the only instance of the class in the whole project when I use a tool to search the entire lib folder for instances of the class. This is definitely not a situation of multiple versions of the class or of other classes existing in one of the jars with a similar name. What could be the cause of this and how can I resolve it?

Comment: `The library gets included in the lib folder after the project builds` How do you package your app? You include it in the lib folder of the ZIP package or the lib folder of the system directory?

Comment: Yes, I include it as a zip folder. I am running the app via AnyPoint Studio using the Run As Configuration option

Comment: I would first confirm that the class is definitely in the build path.Once you can see it under the libraries tab, Mavenize the project. That way you can be sure that it is a satisfied dependency.

Comment: That has already been confirmed. The jar is in the lib folder in the zip. It actually fails at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357). So I believe it has to do with being unable to load the class. Also, don't forget the class compiles and failure only occurs when trying to access the method in the class

Answer (score 0):

Even though if you add the jar in lib folder you need to manually add that jar to your class path.So, that it will be available.

Answer (score 0):

They are 2 possibilities here one is there might be a need of OS specific library to be downloaded and configured in Anypoint Stduio in Run configurations like for SAP we need to point it to the DLL which windows will refer to. Giving below an example.
-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\adm-snandu\AnypointStudio\workspace\

For most of the Class Notfound errors you need to make sure the maven dependency is given in the pom.xml which takes care of downloading all the relevant libraries and referring to them during run time.